# Exporting a XLS with +80.000 records

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to export a XLS file with +80.000 and I'm getting "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: The cell cannot be added".

I tried to upper the "MAXIMUM_ROWS_PER_SHEET" but it didn't worked.

This is my code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    JasperReport relatorioJasper = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(parametros.get("REPORT_JASPER")+"");

    JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaReport);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorioJasper, parametros, dataSource);

    JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
    exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
    exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(out));
    SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
    configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(false);
    configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
    configuration.setCollapseRowSpan(false);
    configuration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenColumns(true);
    // exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.MAXIMUM_ROWS_PER_SHEET, 10000);

    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();


    InputStream relatorios = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    return stream2file(relatorios, parametros.get("REPORT_NAME")+"" ,Constantes.XLS);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return null;
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you post full stack trace [edit] the post

Comment: @user3633580 You can try to debug the code with attached *JasperReports* library source code. You can set break points in places where `new JRException(EXCEPTION_MESSAGE_KEY_CANNOT_ADD_CELL` are raised. For example in *JExcelApiExporter* class. In this case you can catch the exception's reason of 3rd party libraries (POI or JExcelApi)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but it worked with just changing XLS to XLSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think trouble is not in the export. MAXIMUM_ROWS_PER_SHEET can't help you too.
`XLS` can't contain more than 65,536 rows. Try to use `XLSX`.
See [this answer from Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/366468/what-is-the-maximum-allowed-rows-in-a-microsoft-excel-xls-or-xlsx).

Comment: This is the poi limits on different versions https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/SpreadsheetVersion.html